# Use custom JSON serializers with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to get JsonObjects or strings in Json format when using DataSnapshot.getValue()? Maybe I wasn't thorough enough with my search, but I couldn't find a way to use a custom serializer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**:
I haven't had the time for checking out the documentation for the latest SDK but it seems like [there are some options for JSON fields](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#update_your_java_model_objects_numbered).

---

The `getValue()` in `DataSnapshot` returns a `HashMap`.
So in any method of your Firebase listener, you could:

1. Get the value of the DataSnapshot, which will return a `HashMap`:

   ```
   HashMap<String, JSONObject> dataSnapshotValue = (HashMap<String, JSONObject>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
   ```
2. Cast the `Hashmap`to a valid JSON string, using Gson:

   ```
   String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(dataSnapshotValue);
   ```
3. With this valid `jsonString`, cast it as needed:

   ```
   final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
   gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new UserSerializer());
   final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
   User parsedUser = gson.fromJson(jsonString, User.class);
   ```

This gives you the possibility to use anything you want to cast an object from Firebase, you could either use custom serializers, an [ExclusionStrategy](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/ExclusionStrategy.html), or retrieve some values from the `HashMap` directly.

Comment: I someone sees this from the Firebase-Team: What an ugly solution! Converting to a HashMap -> to JSON-String -> serialize to specific type.

Comment: @MikeMitterer I guess you have a better approach then! Click on "Add Another Answer" and enlighten us.

Comment: Sorry man - that was not meant as a critique on the answer. The posting was directed to the FB-Team and their bad GSON support!

Comment: @MikeMitterer oh ok, sorry then

Comment: I can back Mike's comment, it's 2018 and you still can't register a custom serializer..., what a waste of resources

Comment: Absolutely right, no wait it is 2019 and you still can't register a custom de/serializer...

Comment: Right.... wait? It's 2021 and we STILL canN'T do it?

Comment: oh wow 
it is 2022 and still NO custom serializer

Comment: Almost 2023.....

Answer (score 0):

Based on @RominaV answer and in case it may be helpful to someone that's what I have in **Kotlin**:

```
 myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            adapter.clear()

            dataSnapshot.children.forEach {

                val cardMap = it.value
                val json = Gson().toJson(cardMap)
                val card = Gson().fromJson<Card>(json, Card::class.java)

                adapter.add(CardItem(card))
            }

        }
```

And that's my Card class

```
data class Card(var courseId: String, var cardQuestion: String, var cardAnswer: String) {
     constructor() : this("", "", "")
}
```

I can also get the same outcome traversing through the dataSnapshot children this way:

```
dataSnapshot.children.forEach {

        adapter.clear()

        val courseId = it.child("courseId").value as String
        val question = it.child("cardQuestion").value as String
        val answer = it.child("cardAnswer").value as String

        adapter.add(CardItem(Card(courseId, question, answer))
}
```

Thanks. :)