# How to deserialize ISO 8601 datetime from Google Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jackson, gson

### TL; DR

How to migrate POJOs with [ISO8601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format) string datetime fields to Google Firebase Database, allowing automatic deserialization with [Google GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)?

### Description

Given the follwing POJO written using [Jackson annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations):

```
    @JsonIgnoreExtraProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class ChatMessage {

        public String name;
        public String message;

        @JsonFormat(
            shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,
            pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        )
        public Date createdAt;

        @JsonFormat(
            shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,
            pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        )
        public Date updatedAt;

        @JsonIgnore
        public String ignoreThisField;

    }
```

According to [Firebase Database migration for Android](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android?hl=pt-br), this is how and `ChatMessage` would look using only GSON:

```
public class ChatMessage {

    public String name;
    public String message;

    public Date createdAt;
    public Date updatedAt;

    @Exclude
    public String ignoreThisField;
}
```

I have already seeing solutions using [custom deserializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468794/use-custom-json-serializers-with-firebase), but it would require rewrite dozens of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [custom (de)serializer post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468794/use-custom-json-serializers-with-firebase), I created a `Mapper` class that automatically deserialize [ISO 8601 string dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format) into `Date`:

```
public class Mapper {

    private static Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
            .create();

    public static <T> T fromJson(Object object, Class<T> type) {
        String jsonString = GSON.toJson((HashMap<String, JSONObject>) object);
        return GSON.fromJson(jsonString, type);
    }

    public static String toJson(Object object) {
        return GSON.toJson(object);
    }

}
```

and then `ChatMessage` can be obtained from

```
ChatMessage msg = Mapper.fromJson(dataSnapshot.getValue(), ChatMessage.class);
Timber.d(Mapper.toJson(msg));
```