# Firebase custom JSON deserializer

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried searching this on the Firebase Google Groups/Slack/SO but couldn't find anything concrete except [this answer from 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468794/use-custom-json-serializers-with-firebase/36706248#36706248).

I trying to implement a custom JSON deserializer to convert the `DataSnapshot` to an object. The Firebase implement works as expected however I have a few edge cases where the Firestore database may be storing `null` values for fields, or simply not exist. My goal is to provide default values so that I don't have to handle null pointers in each instance. Something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39951187/how-to-do-conditional-gson-deserialization-default-value). Is that possible?

Comment: You can just write code to set default values if you see that they're null.  This won't happen automatically.

Comment: Right, but at some point, that becomes really repetitive or just too much boilerplate if I have a lot of fields to work with. Using a custom deserializer -- like the one I linked -- would allow me to code once and forget about edge cases.